example proof system for arithmetic
I wonder what a complete formalization of arithmetic would look like. According to the Wikipedia page on proof systems it should have the following three components:

Formal language: The set $L$ of formulas admitted by the system, for example, propositional logic or first-order logic.

Rules of inference: List of rules that can be employed to prove theorems from axioms and theorems.

Axioms: Formulas in $L$ assumed to be valid. All theorems are derived from axioms.


Is there material describing fully each of the three components of any of the attempts to formalize arithmetic?

The Peano Axioms are the usual start for arithmetic.

Wiki's entry on [Peano https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#:%7E:text=The%20Peano%20axioms%20define%20the,0%20is%20a%20natural%20number) has the details wrt first-order arithmetic, that is f-o version of the axioms plus f-o predicate logic with equality.

Every math log textbook has all the details: Mendelson, Enderton...

The usual tack taken nowadays is to separate the logical and non-logical aspects.
So for instance, there is a general framework for deductions in first-order logic where the rules of inference and purely logical axioms live. There are many different equivalent versions of this and pretty much any introductory logic text will have one laid out in detail.
And then we can specialize to a particular language (i.e. arithmetic in this case, with non-logical symbols like $(0,1,+,\cdot)$) and add nonlogical axioms, e.g. PA. Many standard introductory texts have material on this as well, as well as books specializing in the incompleteness theorem.
Just to give an example, not as a particular recommendation over the many others, Enderton's A Mathematical Introduction to Logic covers these things.
